# Python code to divide data set by taking reference on date column

Tags: python

I have one data-set having date range through 2007-2015 and want to divide my data set based on the date range.

1. One data-set should have date range from June 2007 to May 2015
2. Other data-set should have date range from June 2015 to Dec 2015

Based on the `Issued_d` column, I want to divide my data-set

[image]

Comment: I don&#39;t see the question here.. . Read the file in (csvreader, pandas,...) and filter via this value e.g. using datetime.. . Can you clarify what do you want to know or where you've got stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can bring that data into Pandas' DataFrame. You may read the documentation, if you aren't familiar with pandas.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

When you have already had that data as a DataFrame, make sure that `issue_d` is a datetime column:

```
your_dataframe[issue_d].dtype
```

If not already of type datetime, do something like:

```
your_dataframe[issue_d] = pd.to_datetime(your_dataframe[issue_d], format='%m%Y')
```

Then you can select/ divide your dataframe by date:

```
df1 = your_dataframe(your_dataframe[issue_d] < '06-2015')
df2 = your_dataframe(your_dataframe[issue_d] > '05-2015')
```